# Деструктивное присваивание. Как вытащить значение элементов массива в переменные

Tags: javascript

У меня есть строка, в которой 4 числа через пробел. Я хочу вытащить эти значения из строки и присвоить 4 разным переменным.

```
var array = inputString.split(' ');
var a = input[0];
var b = input[1];
var c = input[2];
var d = input[3];
```

Но данная запись не совсем короткая, можно как-нибудь это сократить и чтобы переменные были типа `Number`?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать [деструктивное присваивание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), а чтобы привести все элементы массива к типу `Number`, используйте метод [`map(Number)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), если же элемент массива не будет типа `Number`, или его не удастся привести к данному типу, то вы получите `NaN`, потому что значение элемента не является числом:

```
let [a, b, c, d] = inputString.split(' ').map(Number);
```

### Пример:

```js
let inputString = '10 20.5 30 40.5';
let [a, b, c, d] = inputString.split(' ').map(Number);
console.log(a, b, c, d);
```